# Error in pgfplot when big offset is subtracted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, fp

I have some data with a huge offset that I want to plot.
Im using PGF plots, where it's possible to subtract the offset from a whole row in my data.

This works when the offset isn't too big, and/or the delta between ticks isn't to small. otherwise the plot will be all twisted.

See folowing MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   Y
149038832.9 19
149038835.1 18
149038837.3 17
149038839.5 16
149038841.7 15
149038843.9 14
149038846.1 13
149038848.3 12
149038850.5 11
149038852.7 10
149038854.9 9
149038857.1 8
149038859.3 7
149038861.5 6
149038863.7 5
149038865.9 4
149038868.1 3
149038870.3 2
149038872.5 1
149038874.7 0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot table[x expr=(\thisrowno{0}-149038800),y=Y] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example was supposed to give a plot with a straight line, but the result are as follows:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Post-processing the data isn't a possibility, because I'm not allowed to make changes to the datafiles.

However, arcording to [this](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-3/tb105fuster.pdf)(p.5), it's possible to change the mathematical engine from usepackage *pgfmath*(default) to *fp*, which should extend the fixed-point arithmetic. I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: I would guess this is a result of the limited precision of math in TeX. You should consider using an external script to pre-process the data first. You can look on this site (a Google search might be more fruitful with `site:tex.stackexchange.com`) for other information about floating point arithmetic

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use another math engine in the following manner

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   Y
149038832.9 19
149038835.1 18
149038837.3 17
149038839.5 16
149038841.7 15
149038843.9 14
149038846.1 13
149038848.3 12
149038850.5 11
149038852.7 10
149038854.9 9
149038857.1 8
149038859.3 7
149038861.5 6
149038863.7 5
149038865.9 4
149038868.1 3
149038870.3 2
149038872.5 1
149038874.7 0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot table[x expr=({\xinttheiexpr[1]\thisrowno{0}-149038800\relax}),y=Y] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I explain the syntax:

1. `\xinttheiexpr[d] ... \relax` does exact computations with scientific numbers or fractions (no limit on number of digits, but concretely works best with up to a few hundred digits per number) then <strike>truncates</strike> rounds to `d` digits after decimal mark. So far, apart from square root (by default, with `16` digits of precision; but `sqrt(x,P)` will have `P` digits of precision) no non-algebraic functions implemented though. It is also possible to use only macros from package `xintfrac`, but the expression syntax is easier to use.
2. I needed braces to trick the `TikZ parsing it seems.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ha, that's going to come in really handy!

Comment: @Jake I was lucky no `sin`, no `exp`... `;-) `

Comment: That's [your package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint?lang=en)? I'm impressed!

Comment: @Jake yes, thanks. It originated as a package for expandable calculations on big integers. Extension to arbitrary precision floats is in its infancy yet. I haven't even NaN's yet.

Answer (score 4):

To work around the limited precision and the restriction that you can't preprocess the data file, you could truncate the number at the string level before plotting it. You can do that using by using `\pgfplotstablemodifyeachcolumnelement` to loop over the rows, and then extracting the rightmost characters using `\StrRight{\cell}{6}[\result]` (from the `xstring` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents, xstring, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   Y
149038832.9 19
149038835.1 18
149038837.3 17
149038839.5 16
149038841.7 15
149038843.9 14
149038846.1 13
149038848.3 12
149038850.5 11
149038852.7 10
149038854.9 9
149038857.1 8
149038859.3 7
149038861.5 6
149038863.7 5
149038865.9 4
149038868.1 3
149038870.3 2
149038872.5 1
149038874.7 0
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datatable
    \pgfplotstablemodifyeachcolumnelement{X}\of\datatable\as\cell{%
    \StrRight{\cell}{6}[\result]%
    \edef\cell{\result}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot table[x expr=(\thisrowno{0}-8800),y=Y] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but is I cant guarantee that there is the same amount of decimal every time. So is possible to grap the data by cutting away from left instead?

Comment: nevermind I did figure it out myself: \StrGobbleLeft{\cell}{5}[\result]%