# PGFplots: Logarithmic scale showing 1020 insteead of 1024?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make a plot with a base-2 logarithmic axis and everything is turning out great, except that the labels are 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, and **1020**. The last one should be **1024**. I assume that this has something to do with significant digits, but I'm not sure how to change it.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
        xlabel=$n$,
        log basis x=2,
        ymode=log,
        ylabel=Time (sec),
        log ticks with fixed point,
        legend style={at={(0.05,0.95)},
        title={My title},
        anchor=north west}]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (32,0.04)
            (64,0.09)
            (128,0.14)
            (256,0.27)
            (512,0.56)
            (1024,1.66)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (32,0.04)
            (64,0.09)
            (128,0.26)
            (256,0.92)
            (512,5.71)
            (1024,42.14)
        };
        \legend{With minimization,Without minimization}
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: It would be great if you can not just provide the code, but a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I've edited your question to add one, this might help with getting an answer from procrastinating TikZ/PGF experts...

Comment: It definitely seems to be a rounding/significant digit problem. When I add `xtick={32,64,128,256,512,999}` on line 15, eveything is fine. Adding `xtick={32,64,128,256,512,1001}` adds a rounded down *1000* to the x-axis, which is obviously also the case for *1024* (or *1020*). I don't have an answer though...

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a precision issue.

Two possible options:

- Use

  ```
  xticklabel={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
      \pgfmathparse{int(2^\tick)}
      \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
  }
  ```

  This gives the correct results up to `2^21 = 2097152`, after that, you also run into precision problems
- Load the [`xint`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) package (by our own [jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu)!) and then use

  ```
  xticklabel={\xinttheiexpr2^\tick\relax}
  ```

  This works up to a [few hundred digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283452/2552). I tried it up to `2^42 = 4398046511104`, which works correctly. At some point, you probably don't want fixed format output anymore, though.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
        xlabel=$n$,
        log basis x=2,
        ymode=log,
        ylabel=Time (sec),
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,},
        xticklabel={\xinttheiexpr[0]2^\tick\relax},
        legend style={at={(0.05,0.95)},
        title={My title},
        anchor=north west}]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (32,0.04)
            (64,0.09)
            (128,0.14)
            (256,0.27)
            (512,0.56)
            (1024,1.66)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (32,0.04)
            (64,0.09)
            (128,0.26)
            (256,0.92)
            (512,5.71)
            (1024,42.14)
        };
        \legend{With minimization,Without minimization}
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I tried your first suggestion, I got the following error: 'Argument of \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat has an extra }.' It seems that the problem is with the final line, i.e. '\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}'. Do I need something for that?

Comment: Perhaps I am using an old version of pgfplots? I am on version 1.9. Is this only available in a newer version?

Comment: I just now encountered the same issue as Gregory; notably, this had not happened previously, when the document I was working with was smaller, and when I then tried the `xint` version it failed as well. My fix that seems to work for at least small values (<10000, didn't test with more) is to switch to `/pgf/fpu=false` (apparently the default, but making it explicit here is probably good anyway).